# How to convert string into number using expression transformation in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I have source column(amount) with datatype string, contains the datas like $793.00, $5791.00,...

I need to load this same data into the target table column(amount) with datatype NUMBER

how can i get this same data with '$' symbol in target by using expression transformation in informatica?

anyone help me please, thanks in advance.

---

Comment: @madhina, do you mean "with" or "without" the $ symbol ? If you wish to convert this to a number, you'll have to strip out the '$' symbol.

Answer (score 3):

TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(AMOUNT,INSTR(AMOUNT,'$')+1,LENGTH(AMOUNT)-1))

or if it's always the first character and you don't have to worry about spaces

TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(AMOUNT,2,LENGTH(AMOUNT)-1))

Comment: Why waste that Length function for no reason?  Just leave out that optional last parameter of SUBSTR.

Answer (score 1):

You can take source column "amount" into one expression element, say "AMOUNT_INPUT" and add a new item in that expression such that **"AMOUNT_OUTPUT"** in this make a expression as **"TO_NUMBER(AMOUNT_INPUT)"**

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Informatica do not support `TO_NUMBER()`. If that is the case with the version you are using, you will need to use one of the following, as appropriate for your use case:

- `TO_INTEGER()`
- `TO_FLOAT()`
- `TO_DECIMAL()`

See the [reference of Informatica functions](http://informaticatutorials-naveen.blogspot.com/2011/07/functions-in-informatica.html#axzz2kezqtELw) for usage details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below logic to get the desired result -
REPLACESTR(1,AMOUNT,'$','')